# why can't i access a function of a web control?

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have the next question:

I've got an .aspx which contains a lot of web controls, this is the one i care:

```
//line 5
<%@ Register src="Controls/UCAttachments.ascx" tagname="UCAttachments" tagprefix="uc1" %>
```

```
//line 430
<uc1:UCAttachments ID="UCAttachments" runat="server" Visible="false" />
```

On the selected index changed event of a combo box, i need to call a function of the web control, this is the code of the .aspx.cs.

```
private void cbo_SelectedIndexChanged( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
 if(this.op == 1){
 UCAttachments.visible=true;
 UCAttachments.loadById(this.id); <-this doesnt work.
//Even tho, i can access all the other functions of UCAttachments.
//More infor abkout the error:
//'CONTROL' does not contain a definition for 'loadById'and no accessible //method accepting first argument...

 }
}
```

```
public partial class Controls_UCAttachments: System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
//lots of functions
  public void loadById( string id )
  {
    string query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID = " +id;
    //more code
    return ;

  }
}
```

Comment: public voidloadById( string id) is that your code? Should probably be public void loadById(string id)

Comment: sorry @KnuturO i didn't realize, i just fixed it, the code is correctly written, i didn't copy pasted

Answer (score -1, accepted):

so.. very curious thing.

when you have a form which contains a lot of user controls, you need to wait for the metadata file to reload the new methods you've created.

So i closed my visual studio and re opeened a minutes later and the bug desapeared.

Answer (score 0):

you have to make this method static

```
public partial class Controls_UCAttachments 
{
    //lots of functions
    static public void loadById(string id)
    {
        string query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID = " + id;
        //more code
        return;

    }
}
```

and you can call  using this syntax

```
Controls_UCAttachments.loadById(this.id);
```